# How to make custom shape div, or manipulate divs

Tags: html, css, image

[image]

I want to make a div that is like that, but i have no clue. I can do it with svg or images, but that is not how i want it. Here is my code

HTML

```
<div class="FooterWhite"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.FooterWhite {
background-color:white;
height:50%;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: yeah. I know that. It was just an "in the moment mistake". But thanks anyways.

Comment: To the problem at hand

Comment: I have 2 question: 1) do you need the shape to be responsive? 2) do you need to add content in the shape?

Comment: @web-tiki That's the question :) One solution would be http://jsbin.com/fixew/2/edit which may/may not fit all the needs.

Comment: @HashemQolami yes, + user3219918 an other question that comes to my mind is do you have a plain color background or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
 .shape { 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 70px; 
    background: #000;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

.shape:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 50px solid #f00;
    border-bottom:50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
}.shape:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border: 50px solid #f00;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right:50px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left:100px;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6J7V/1/)

Comment: This was really helpful and gets to the point of what i wanted to know. Thanks.